# Can I Use 20w50 Engine oil for APACHE RTR 160BS4?

Tags: motorcycle, oil

Can i use 20w50 engine oil for apache rtr160 bs4?
my mechanic suggested to use it

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is the Owner's Manual for this vehicle:

[Apache RTR 160 Manual](https://www.tvsmotor.com/pdf/Manuals-Apache-RTR-160-NEW.pdf)

On page 32 is calls for "SAE 10W-30 API-SL JASO MA2" specification oil.  I did not find 20W-50 listed as an acceptable alternative.

So NO, you should not use 20W-50 in this bike.

Comment: Link does not work. If it's in a hot climate then 20w-50 could be okay(or even recommended).
For example thats how it is for some kawasakis. the recommended oil is 10w-40 - except later on in the manual there's a chart that shows which oils are okay for what outside temperatures(-50 being 50C). That's what the numbers on the oil signify anyways.

10w-30 would top out at outside temperatures of 30 celcius. It is not out of question that 20w-50 would be the correct choice for parts of India. In most parts of the world the chart allows for almost any oil(0 to 30 celcius).